# Python list replacement

Tags: python, list, replace

How to replace each element in a list with an element in the same position from another list?  I thought something like this might work:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['a_replaced', 'b_replaced', 'c_replaced']
text = open(textfile, 'r')
 n = 0
for line in  text:
    line = line[0:len(line)-1]
    line.replace(col[n], outcol[n])
    print line
    n + 1
```

But it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you declaring col and outcol? Are they supposed to be list1 and list2?

Comment: If you meant increment `n`, you need to write `n += 1`. But I'm having a tough time trying to figure out what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 3):

5 things:

- You reference `col` and `outcol` which I assume are actually `list1` and `list2`.
- `list1` and `list2` are different sizes, this will crash
- You're not checking the bounds on `n`, so if your text file is longer than 4 lines it will crash
- The line `n + 1` doesn't actually do anything, it should be `n += 1`
- `line.replace` doesn't do an inline replace, it returns a new string.

So change it to `line = line.replace(...)`.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish. This program replaces `a` in line 1 with `a_replaced`, `b` in line 2 with `b_replaced`, `c` in line 3 with `c_replaced`, and `d` in line 4 with `d_replaced`.

```
replacements = [('a', 'a_replaced'), ('b', 'b_replaced'), ('c', 'c_replaced'), ('d', 'd_replaced')]
text = open(textfile, 'r')
n = 0
for line in  text:
    if n >= len(replacements):
        break
    print line[:-1].replace(replacements[n][0], replacements[n][1])
    n += 1
```

However if your're trying to apply all replacements on each line, here's how:

```
replacements = [('a', 'a_replaced'), ('b', 'b_replaced'), ('c', 'c_replaced'), ('d', 'd_replaced')]
text = open(textfile, 'r')
for line in  text:
    line = line[:-1]
    for oldtext, newtext in replacements:
        line = line.replace(oldtext, newtext)
    print line
```

Or a shorter version of the above program:

```
replacements = [('a', 'a_replaced'), ('b', 'b_replaced'), ('c', 'c_replaced'), ('d', 'd_replaced')]
text = open(textfile, 'r').read()
for oldtext, newtext in replacements:
    text = text.replace(oldtext, newtext)
print text,
```

Answer (score 0):

replace returns new string. You need `line = line.replace(col[n], outcol[n])`.

Answer (score 0):

replace doesn't change the string, it returns a copy of the modified string.

```
line = line.replace(col[n], outcol[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve, although it is difficult to tell from the code that you have provided:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['a_replaced', 'b_replaced', 'c_replaced', 'd_replaced']
text = open(textfile, 'r')
for line in text:
    for index, old in enumerate(list1):
        line = line.replace(old, list2[index])
    print line
text.close()
```

This should work. Comment to clarify